# I have huge reads on my firebase, how to freeze objects for my React Firebase app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have like 30k++ huge data from my firebase. The bad thing about it is, everytime I click back button on my React page, it fetches that 30k++ data again, it hurts the wallet.

Is there anything I can do to solve it?

this is the useEffect I use in my home page

```js
 useEffect(() => {
        // first 5 posts
        Form.allPosts()
            .then((res) => {
                setSalesLastMonth(res.posts);
                setLastKey(res.lastKey);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        Form.postsToday()
            .then((res) => {
                setSales(res.posts)
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }, []);
```

this is an example of the firebase function:

```js
postsToday: async function () {
        try {
            const yesterday = new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));

            let today = new Date();
            const data = await firestore
                .collectionGroup('form')
                .orderBy("Created At", "desc")
                .where('Created At', '>=', yesterday)
                .where('Created At', '<=', today)
                .get()

            let posts = [];
            let lastKey = "";
            data.forEach((doc) => {
                posts.push({
                    id: doc.id,
                    etc etc

                });
                lastKey = doc.data()['Created At']
            });
            return { posts, lastKey };
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    },
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is to [enable Firestore's client-side persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence), which means that client will keep a disk-based cache that it can read documents from that it has seen recently.

Another way to reduce the reads is to only load the data the user sees. It seems unlikely that the user will check all 30K forms, so I'd recommend [using cursors/queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) to implement pagination or infinite scrolling to load only the first page of data initially, and load the rest on demand as needed. You seem to already be tracking the `lastKey`, which is the main thing you'll need for both.

Finally, also consider if each user needs to perform this query individually, or whether you can perform them once and share the results with all users. For example, you could create a [data bundle](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/bundles) for things that all users see, [serve that bundle from a CDN](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/serve-bundles), and then inject that into the offline cache.